# Embed p5.js sketch into a react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, p5.js

I have created a p5.js sketch which I want to use in the bottom portion of my home page. I wouldn't imagine it to be too hard, simply put it in a div at the bottom portion of my . What I need help with is actually "connecting" my react project with my sketch.

I am using VSCode to develop my p5.js project. I also initialized my project using npm create vite@latest and my project is currently at that default installation. So, where and how can I add my sketch.js into my app?

Comment: Why would it need a connection between the two? Just make React generate the html that you need to run your p5.js sketch (which is just a div with a script injection for p5js in the head, as a side effect, "if not already injected")

Comment: How would i make React generate the html file with the script injection? I am currently looking at multiple sources, some which say to download the libraries and others that use a cloudflare link. I am not too sure what to use

Comment: Whatever you want? CDN urls are convenient but if you're hosting your app on something like S3 then there's not much point in the CDN link and you can just as easily load it as a relative file.

Comment: Sorry I am still a little lost! Say I have my sketch file (.js), and I wanted it to use it within my react app. Where/how exactly can I make react be able to use the sketch file?

Comment: by ignoring React entirely: first figure out _how you would do this without React_, because adding React does not change any of that, all it changes is how you generate the page "HTML". What that HTML is, and where your files live, etc. is still the same, all that's changed is who writes the HTML: you vs React. Put your sketch in a place that you web page has access to, add a script tag in the head (if not added already) that loads the p5js library, and make react generate the html element(s) that you need to run your sketch.

Comment: I have got it working with a simple  index.html, but now I want to add it to my React app. In my react project's index.html, I have added the:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.7.0/p5.js">` `</script<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.7.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>>`

Is this the correct spot to put the script tags? If so, I want to add this sketch to my App.jsx, Do I just put:

`<script src="DIRECTORY"></script> `

simply into my App() function?

Comment: Remember to that that [in your post](/help/how-to-ask). To move that to the react side you add a useEffect with an empty dependency array (so it only runs once) and then you write normal JS in the effect function that checks if there's a script element with id `p5js` in the `head`, and if not, creates it with the src pointing to that CDN location. _Or_ you can even keep that script tag in your main HTML template if you want it loaded on every page.